# breqn with Miktex creates strange line breaks. Bug?

Tags: miktex2.9, breqn

The following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
V_{t}=\left({a}_{t} V^{norm} \left(C_{t}^{\eta} \left(1-N_{t}\right)^{1-{\eta}}\right)^{\frac{1-{\sigma}}{\theta_v}}+{\beta}_{t} {\left(E_t V_{t+1}^{1-\sigma}\right)}_{t}^{\frac{1}{\theta_v}}\right)^{\frac{{\theta_v}}{1-{\sigma}}}
\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

with Miktex results in

[image]

although there is no reason to break the equation. This was not the case some time ago. A friend of mine cannot reproduce the problem on his Mac. It also does not occur in Overleaf. Thus, it may be a bug. My distribution is up to date (pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.6)).

Overleaf's Tex Live 2020 in contrast produces

[image]

Comment: `breqn` has a lot of issues. Generally we do not recommend using it,

Comment: Apparently, the useless `\left` and `\right`, besides producing a horrible output, utterly confuse `breqn`.

Comment: miktex will not be relevant here but the version of latex and breqn will be but you have given no information about that. Unrelated but use v^{\mathrm{norm}}` math italic font is designed to separate the letters so they look like a product of variables, not a word)

Comment: Whilst we can argue about the usefulness of `breqn` (specifically), auto-breaking (generally) or the input here, there is something up: I don't see the break with TL'20 final.

Comment: I would prefer a different way of producing output as well, without the unnecessary brackets around atoms and `breqn`, but the piece of code is algorithmically generated. So there is a need to avoid double sub- and superscripts and there is no human checking of bracket sizes or equation lengths for that matter. The reason I posted here is that it worked in the past as @JosephWright pointed out.

Comment: Better not to use breqn. I stopped using it few years ago. It breaks many things, and does not work with tex4ht either. I had many questions here asking for help when I used it due to many problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is new hooks added to paragraph code. I've not worked out where the fix should go 'properly' yet, but you can locally restore things using

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\AddToHook{env/dmath/begin}{\tex_everypar:D { } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
V_{t}=\left({a}_{t} V^{norm} \left(C_{t}^{\eta} \left(1-N_{t}\right)^{1-{\eta}}\right)^{\frac{1-{\sigma}}{\theta_v}}+{\beta}_{t} {\left(E_t V_{t+1}^{1-\sigma}\right)}_{t}^{\frac{1}{\theta_v}}\right)^{\frac{{\theta_v}}{1-{\sigma}}}
\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```